# Can you Ready a 1st-level or higher spell when you already have cast a 1st-level or higher spell as a bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, readied-action, action-economy

A wizard casts *misty step* (a 2nd-level bonus action spell) to get to an advantageous position.

The rules state that if you want to cast another spell with your action **this turn**, it has to be a 1-action cantrip. However, the wizard wants to cast *silent image*.

Can the wizard use the Ready action on the *silent image* spell so that the spell is cast in the same round, but not the same turn?

The rules say that readying a spell requires you to cast it as normal, and when the trigger comes you just release the energy, meaning you have to concentrate until then. I would rule that the spell is thus cast on the same turn, even if its energy is released on a different turn, so it would be against the rule.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### No, you can't.

When you use the *ready action* you **cast** the spell in your turn and hold it.

*PHB p. 193* (emphasis mine):

> When you ready a spell, you **cast it as normal but hold its energy**

If you cast a bonus action spell, you cannot cast another spell unless it is a cantrip with the casting time of 1 action.

*PHB p. 202* (emphasis mine):

> [...] You can't **cast** another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.